# MySQL + Python: Not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to do an `INSERT` into `MySQL` using the `cursor.execute(sql, args)` syntax. This is what I currently have:

```
# data = {...}
qmarks = ', '.join('?' * len(data))   
query = "INSERT INTO title (%s) VALUES (%s)" %(qmarks, qmarks) 
args = data.keys() + data.values()
print len(args), print len(data)
cursor.execute(query, args)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I checked the length of `args` (22) and `quarks` (11 x 2 = 22), and they seem to be the same. What is causing this error, and what do I need to change?

**Update**: When I try and do the string formatting using `%s`, it also throws an error:

```
>>> data={'provider':'asdf', 'vendor_id': '1234'}
>>> format = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(data)) 
>>> query = "INSERT INTO title (%s) VALUES (%s)" %(format, format)
>>> query
'INSERT INTO title (%s, %s) VALUES (%s, %s)'
>>> cursor.execute(query, args)
Traceback (most recent call last):
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near ''vendor_id', 'provider') VALUES ('1234', 'asdf')' at line 1")
```

I think this has to do with the fact that the column definitions are strings:

```
INSERT INTO title ('vendor_id', 'provider') VALUES ('1234', 'asdf')
```

instead of:

```
INSERT INTO title (vendor_id, provider) VALUES ('1234', 'asdf')
```

Is there a way to use string formatting here but pass a *variable* instead of a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQLdb, you want to have `%s` in the final query, not `?`, you will also need to enter the column names directly into the query instead of using the `%s` replacement for them:

```
# data = {...}
columns = ', '.join(data.keys())
format = ', '.join(['%s'] * len(data))
query = "INSERT INTO title (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (columns, format)
cursor.execute(query, data.values())
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the string formatting, but it is still throwing some sort of syntax error (see above).

Comment: @David542 - I think that is caused by the quotes around the column names, pretty sure you will need to insert the field column names into your query directly and then only have the `%s` replacement for the values.  So it would look like: `INSERT INTO title (vendor_id, provider) VALUES (%s, %s)`.

Comment: But then I lose the ordering of the `dict` (in the dict I have about 100 k,v pairs)

Comment: @David542 - Actually no, if you insert the columns using `data.keys()` and then insert the values using `data.values()` without any intervening modifications to the dictionary (as in my edit), the columns and values are guaranteed to correspond directly.  This is in the documentation for [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).